# (Error) mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

El problema esta en que es un ejemplo pequeño para registrar datos en la base de datos y al mismo tiempo consultarlos, puse un registro de ejemplo que su clave primaria es el numero "1" y ese me arroja toda la información sin ningún problema, pero cuando pongo el dato que corresponde, en este caso una curp de 18 dígitos con letras y números, aparece el error, estuve checando y no se cual es la solución, apenas estoy comenzando con bases de datos.

El codigo (Cave aclarar que no hay ningún dato escrito de forma errónea, todos tienen su nombre bien):

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Base De Datos</title>
  
</head>
<body bgcolor="pink">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4">



    <center><h1>Clientes</h1></center>

    <center><form method="POST" action="registro.php" >

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="curp">Curp</label>
      <input type="text" name="curp" class="form-control" id="curp">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
      <label for="nombre">Nombre </label>
      <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control" id="nombre" >
  </div>

   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="dir">Direccion </label>
      <input type="text" name="dir" class="form-control" id="dir">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
      <label for="mail">Email </label>
      <input type="text" name="mail" class="form-control" id="mail">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
      <label for="tel">Telefono </label>
      <input type="text" name="tel" class="form-control" id="tel">
  </div>
    
    <center>
      <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-success" name="btn1">
      <input type="submit" value="Consultar" class="btn btn-info" name="btn2">
    </center>

  </form></center>



  <?php

    if(isset($_POST['btn1']))
    {
      include("abrir_conexion.php");

      $curp = $_POST['curp'];
      $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
      $dir = $_POST['dir'];
      $mail = $_POST['mail'];
      $tel = $_POST['tel'];

      mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT INTO $clientes (curp,nombre,direccion,email,telefono) values ('$curp','$nombre','$dir','$mail','$tel')");
      //La variable $Conexion viene del archivo "Abrir_Conexion", la cual nos conectara a la base de datos
      //y de paso hacemos el registro de datos.
      
      include("cerrar_conexion.php");
      echo "Se insertaron Correctamente";
    }

    if(isset($_POST['btn2']))
    {
      include("abrir_conexion.php");

        $curp = $_POST['curp'];
        if($curp=="") //VERIFICO QUE AGREGEN UN DOCUMENTO OBLIGATORIAMENTE. 
          {echo "Digita un documento por favor. (Ej: 123)";}
        else
        {  
            $resultados = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM $clientes WHERE curp = $curp");
          while ($consulta = mysqli_fetch_array($resultados)) // Linea donde me marca el error
          {
            echo 
            "
              <table width=\"100%\" border=\"1\">
                <tr>
                  <td><b><center>Curp</center></b></td>
                  <td><b><center>Nombre</center></b></td>
                  <td><b><center>Direccion</center></b></td>
                  <td><b><center>Email</center></b></td>
                  <td><b><center>Telefono</center></b></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>".$consulta['curp']."</td>
                  <td>".$consulta['nombre']."</td>
                  <td>".$consulta['direccion']."</td>
                  <td>".$consulta['email']."</td>
                  <td>".$consulta['telefono']."</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            ";
          }
        }

      include("cerrar_conexion.php");
    }
  ?>



  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>



  
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Que tal , te recomiendo que antes de hacer un "while" valida si tu variable $resultados arroja un valor , ya que no puedes recorrer un resultado en null  , puedes validar de la siguiente manera $row_total = mysqli_num_rows($resultados); si $row_total es mayor a 0 continuas con el while de lo contrario indicas que no hay coincidencias con tu consulta

Answer (score 0):

En la consulta que realizas, la variable *$curp* comentas que es una clave compuesta por números y **letras**. En ese caso, debes realizar la consulta entrecomillando dicha variable:

```
$resultados = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM $clientes WHERE curp = '$curp'");
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias <3 aaaa